# Android Location.convert throwing illegal argument exception

Tags: android, location

This sentence is throwing `IllegalArgumentException`. I still can't figure out whats wrong with this format, its in `[+-]DDD:MM.MMMMM` as documentation says.

`double latitude = Location.convert("-19:59.646");`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the Android platform code for Location.convert(String coordinate) doesn't allow for minute decimal values greater than 59:

https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/location/java/android/location/Location.java#L255

Try using the FORMAT_SECONDS or FORMAT_DEGREES format instead as specified in the Location API docs:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html

For example, your number in FORMAT_SECONDS (DDD:MM:SS.SSSSS) would be -19:59:38.76.

So the code would be:

```
double latitude = Location.convert("-19:59:38.76");
```

I verified that this works on Android using the FORMAT_SECONDS format.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to match that format exactly, so pad it with zeros.

```
double latitude = Location.convert( "-019:59.64600" );
```